# How to manage VBA scripts for a complex form?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to have a complex form that uses various VBA script files.
But when I reference another module, the "Me" doesn't work. Is there any way to use various modules and be like a single file? or what other best practices can you give me?
The problem, is that Im using VBA for 2 days..

Comment: Having multiple modules in the same project shouldn't be a problem, as long as the procedures you need are `Public`. In what context is "the Me" not working? Show us some code!

Comment: What kind of modules are you talking about? It's only class modules that use the Me keyword, either form class modules or standalone class modules. Plain standalone code modules cannot use the Me keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have a procedure, "DoSomethingWithForm", in a standard module.  Modify it to expect a form reference as a parameter.

```
Public Sub DoSomethingWithForm(ByRef frm As Form)
    MsgBox "The name of this form is " & frm.Name
End Sub
```

Then your form can call the procedure like this:

```
Private Sub cmdWhoAmI_Click()
    DoSomethingWithForm Me
End Sub
```

Comment: so for each outside module i need to pass the form as argument?

Comment: You don't have to.  In the outside module, you could refer to an open form as `Forms!form_name` or `Forms("form_name")` ... but then you have to change the module when/if you change `form_name`.  In the way I suggested, code won't break when form is re-named.